Android Gradle Plugin not updating (Android Studio)
I have downloaded a library that requires targetSdk version 34, compileSdk version 34, and minSdkVersion 24 currently mine is 33, 33, and 21 respectively. My Android Gradle Plugin(AGP)
version is 7.4.2 but if we want to use targetSdk version 34 we have to update our  Android Gradle Plugin(AGP) version as version 7.4.2 was tested up to sdk 33.
My gradle version is 8.1.1
Whenever I try to update the version the spinner keeps spinning and I get an error showing IDE error occurred  
When I open the error details this is what it shows
java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.android.ide.common.repository.AgpVersion$Companion.tryParse, parameter value
    at com.android.ide.common.repository.AgpVersion$Companion.tryParse(AgpVersion.kt)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessorKt.isUpdatablePluginDependency(AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessor.kt:1106)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpVersionRefactoringProcessor.findComponentUsages(AgpVersionRefactoringProcessor.kt:160)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpUpgradeComponentRefactoringProcessor.computeIsAlwaysNoOpForProject(AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessor.kt:909)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpUpgradeComponentRefactoringProcessor$isAlwaysNoOpForProject$1.run(AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessor.kt:800)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.kt:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.AgpUpgradeComponentRefactoringProcessor.isAlwaysNoOpForProject(AgpUpgradeRefactoringProcessor.kt:800)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModelKt.activeComponentsForNecessity(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:748)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModelKt.access$activeComponentsForNecessity(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:1)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.refreshTree$populateNecessity(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:509)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.refreshTree(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:514)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.setEnabled(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:476)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.access$setEnabled(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:87)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.upgrade.ui.UpgradeAssistantWindowModel$parseAndSetEnabled$1.run(UpgradeAssistantWindowModel.kt:470)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.smartInvokeLater$lambda$16(DumbServiceImpl.kt:405)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:208)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$4.run(ApplicationImpl.java:478)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:690)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:593)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithoutImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1485)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:593)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:369)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:997)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:405)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)


Why is my AGP version not updating? And how to update it now?
Edit:
This is my build.gradle file :
As you can see I have added 8.2.0 version to react-native-plugin and I have also changed the gradle version to 8.2 but I still get this error while compiling the code :
We recommend using a newer Android Gradle plugin to use compileSdk = 34
This Android Gradle plugin (7.4.2) was tested up to compileSdk = 33

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin:8.2.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        //  implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    }
}

This is my grade-wrapper.properties file:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


Update android studio and try

@Arul, I had updated android studio. I have the latest version(Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1)

Try to manually update both gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties and AGP version in the top-level build.gradle.   Sdk 34 requires gradle to be atleast 8.2 and AGP to be atleast 8.2.0

@ltp I did that but the plugin version is still not updating

@MuneebaDilawaze, I don't know what you meant cause I said to "manually" update it. We can help better if you share your gradle files.

@ltp Thanks I have added my files you can have a look them.

@MuneebaDilawaze, try to specify the AGP version  - com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0
